# cakephp and more than one checkbox

Tags: security, cakephp, checkbox

I'm not doing anything fancy with habtm.

What i'm trying to do is have multiple checkboxes in cakephp, and, well, use them.

So i have this code in my view:

```
<div class="deleteButton">
    <?php echo $form->input('', array('type'=>'checkbox',
    'value'=>$video['Video']['id'], 'label'=>false, 'hiddenField'=>false,
    'id'=>false, 'multiple'=>true)); ?>
</div>
```

and this gives me this html in the rendered page:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="30" name="data[Videos]">
<input type="checkbox" value="31" name="data[Videos]">
<input type="checkbox" value="32" name="data[Videos]">
```

Now, when i select this in the html and submit, i only get ONE value in the controller:
    ...
    pr($this->data);
    ...

Looks like cakephp is overwriting the values stored somehow, because the ONE value i get is always the last checked checkbox value.

What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE: Oh god i hate cakephp

Using this: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/05/multiple-checkboxes/

Or rather, this:: 
    input($video['Video']['id'], array('type'=>'checkbox', 'value'=>$video['Video']['id'], 'label'=>false, 'hiddenField'=>false, 'multiple'=>true)); ?>

(i made $video['Video']['id'] the first entry, which is for ids, apparently)

My request is now black-holed by cakephp's completely ridic blackhole in the Security component. Honest, WHY doesn't the 404 page just have a toggleable error? Now i have to work out how to get a meaningful error from it...

any ideas are welcome!

UPDATE:SOLVED:
Huh, instead I needed:

```
<?php echo $form->input("Video".$video['Video']['id']."id", array('type'=>'checkbox', 'value'=>$video['Video']['id'], 'label'=>false, 'hiddenField'=>false, 'multiple'=>true)); ?>
```

That is, i wrapped the $video['Video']['id'] with "Video" and "id".

NFI why this works, anyone have any ideas, i'll mark you as right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Looks like cakephp is overwriting the values stored somehow, because the ONE value i get is always the last checked checkbox value.

it wasn't cake's fault... if you have two or more inputs with the same name (in your case 'data[Videos]') php will only use the last value to create the $_POST variable.. it like in a GET request if you do something like:

```
mysite.com/intex.php?attr=1&attr=2&attr=3
```

You solved it by adding the video id in the field name. So now the generated html is something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="30" name="data[Videos1]">
<input type="checkbox" value="31" name="data[Videos2]">
<input type="checkbox" value="32" name="data[Videos3]">
```

so as you can see,now all the input names are different and nothing gets overwritten.

However, instead of giving the names by yourself, you could use the '[multiple](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/complete/1383/Form#options-multiple-1395)' option and the '[options](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/complete/1383/Form#options-options-1394)' option to create all the checkboxes using only one statement. Something like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('video',array('options'=> array('Value 1'=>'Label 1',
                                                       'Value 2'=>'Label 2',
                                                       'Value 3'=>'Label 3'
                                                       ),
                                      'multiple' => 'checkbox'
        ));
```

It's all in the doc ;)

Hope this helps

Comment: If i'm using a foreach php loop to create the checkboxes - or at least, that's what i was doing - is there an elegant way to create the array you've suggested? That is, I don't have a clue how *many* checkboxes i need (it is a delete this checkbox, so it depends how many the user has to delete), so i cannot pre-code the array you've suggested!

Comment: You could use the [Set Class](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1487/Set) to transform your array and use it in the `input()`

Comment: OR - because the Set class is too often more clever than useful for me - I can just create the *array* in the loop (btw, i went with the solution i posted to the question - but it is theoretical tuesday!) and then, outside the loop, just run the code you suggest *using the arrar from the loop* as input!

Answer (score 0):

in the $form->input() first parameter is model.field. In first case you did not specified the field, so they all went in $this->data['Videos'] instead $this->data['Videos']['cb1'],$this->data['Videos']['cb2'],$this->data['Videos']['cb3'].

even you create the form with model:

`$form->create('modelName'));`

it is good habit to specify the field too:

`$form->input('modelName.fieldname', array());`