# CakePHP only selecting last checkbox in a loop

Tags: php, cakephp

I found other people that had the same problem when trying to select multiple checkboxes, only the last one is selected. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049995/cakephp-checkbox-multiple-select-just-sends-the-value-of-last-selected-checkbox) and [here is another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831098/cakephp-and-more-than-one-checkbox).

People have suggested using options like this

```
echo $this->Form->input('video',array('options'=> array('Value 1'=>'Label 1',
                                                   'Value 2'=>'Label 2',
                                                   'Value 3'=>'Label 3'
                                                   ),
                                  'multiple' => 'checkbox'
    ));
```

I don't think either of these answer my question. My checkboxes are generated in a loop, but everyone suggested using "options" to set the values. I have no idea how many checkboxes are going to be generated so I don't see how this would work.

```
<table>
<?
    echo $this->Form->create(null,array(
                    'onsubmit'=>'return confirm("Are you sure you want to archive?'));
?>              
    <th>Order ID</th><th>Order Date</th><th>Order Total</th><th>Status</th><th>View</th><th>Select to Archive</th>
    <?php foreach ($orders as $order): 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['orderid'];?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $formatted_date." ".$time; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['total'];?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['order_status'];?> </td>
            <td><a href="/orders/details/<?php echo $order['Order']['orderid']; ?>"/>View Order</a> </td>
            <td><? echo $this->Form->checkbox('archive_value', array('hiddenField' => false, 'value' => $order['Order']['orderid'])); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php //options for the archiving values

$archive_options = array(
                'selected' => 'Archive Selected Orders',
                'filled' => 'Archive All Filled Orders',
            );
?>  
<table class = "table_order_status">
<tr>
    <td>
        <?
        echo $this->Form->input('archive_values', array('options' => $archive_options, 'value' => $select_value, 'name' => 'archive'));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?
        echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); 
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending a period to the end of the input element's name, i.e. `video.` (derived from [this forum post](http://network-13.com/thread/3647-Creating-checkbox-arrays-with-CakePHP)). This will apparently cause the elements to adopt the array name style notation, e.g. `video[]`, though it might be `Model.video[]`. In any case, this should allow you to receive all of the checked values back in the form data.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I didn't see it in the cookbook, strange.